# Errors writing to MongoDB Primary/Master replica set member from Java using Mongo driver

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

I am having an issue with migrating an application to a more distributed architecture. Specifically, I recently began migrating an application into a MongoDB replicaSet where all members communicate using a local subnet inside a virtual cloud. The replicaSet works fine as far as propagating data written from Primary out to secondaries. There are two Java application servers that mostly perform read operations, however they do need to occasionally perform write operations as well. Each server hosting the Java application servers also contain their own secondary mongodb instance running locally.

Specifically, the issue I have is regarding Java using the MongoDB driver which is  wrapped with Jongo. I am using `MongoClientOptions.Builder()` to set `readPreference(ReadPreference.nearest());` which should typically read from the mongodb instance running on the local machine since it will have the least latency. Regardless, read operations work just fine across those two Java servers, and the `rs.status()` command returns a healthy configuration.

When trying to perform a write operation it fails, and my error shows:

`{"timestamp":1427131553387,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.mongodb.CommandFailureException","message":"{ \"serverUsed\" : \"localhost:27017\" , \"note\" : \"from execCommand\" , \"ok\" : 0.0 , \"errmsg\" : \"not master\"}", ...}`

Suggesting that it is trying to perform the write operation on the local mongodb instance (a Secondary member in the replicaSet). It was my understanding that by connecting to any member of a MongoDB replicaSet that the write operations would automatically be sent to the member marked as Master/Primary?

**More details:**

MongoDB is version 2.6.7

The settings are pulled from a simple YAML file

**application.yml**

```
mapserver.mongo:
  database: "maps"
  port: 27017
  host: "localhost"
```

---

Then in the application instantiated with a call to:
`return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(this.getHost(), this.getPort()), this.getOptions());`

---

Perhaps I am missing something in the setup that is necessary for the Java MongoDB driver (and/or Jongo) to determine the members in the replicaSet and their role, and channel the write operations to the current Master in the set? To clarify, there is a NodeJS server portion which is a separate server instance from any of these Java/Seconday-MongoDB servers and separate from the Primary MongoDB instance, yet it can write correctly to the Primary/Master without issue so it should not be a firewall issue. Any ideas or help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of the driver are you using? Try passing in multiple `ServerAddresses` for replica set members (as a list) to the `MongoClient` call - the simplest explanation is that, because you only passed in one address, it's not taking the `MongoClient` to be a replica set connection, so it's sending writes to the secondary.

Comment: @wdberkeley thanks for reply - I was able to debug and discover a few issues, one of which you touched on. It seems that you must supply more than one `ServerAddress` for the Java driver to determine that you are using a ReplicaSet - issue remains that it seems to not discover the other members on its own but rather I need to specify ALL members in MongoClient, which is unacceptable since addresses can change and members can be added/removed over time which would require recompilation at worst or, at best, a reboot of server after altering YAML config file with address changes to Mongos.